# How to animate the textColor property of an UILabel?

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation

For some reason, when I try to animate `textColor`, it won't work. The `textColor` just suddenly changes from A to B. Is it possible to animate it, for example, red to black?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This answer is obsolete, and is not a good solution for the original question. @strange 's answer below is much better and should be used instead of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20892927/76559

//Old answer below

The `textColor` property is not specified as being animatable in the docs, so I don't think you can do it with a simple UIView animations block...

This could probably be done pretty crudely with an `NSTimer` firing every couple of milliseconds, each time setting the colour gradually from one to the other.

I say this is crude because it would require an array or some other container of preset colour values going from the start colour to the finish colour, and I'm sure there's a way you could do this using core animation or something, I just don't know what it is.

Comment: or: a function that throws out an array with RGB values between A and B and a given percentage. Don't know anything about color algorithms though.

Comment: here are good workarounds:
[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442774/is-uilabels-backgroundcolor-not-animatable/6442868#6442868)
and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3947389/1076848)

thanks to Anna Karenina

Comment: You should use `CADisplayLink` rather than `NSTimer` for manually driving animations because it is synchronised with display updates. See [WWDC 2014 Session 236: Building Interruptible and Responsive Interactions](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014-236/) at about 13:00.

Comment: this should NOT be the accepted answer any longer even if it was true at the time. see strange's answer below

Comment: Stack Overflow won't allow me to delete this obsolete answer, as it has been accepted. Checkout @strange's answer below.

Answer (score 211):

Instead, have you tried using a crossfade transition on the object itself like this, it'll give you a nice fade-in fade-out effect from one color to another:

**Objective C**

```
[UIView transitionWithView:myLabel duration:0.25 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{
    myLabel.textColor = NEW_COLOR;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
}];
```

**Swift 5**

```
UIView.transition(with: creditsLabel, duration: 0.25, options: .transitionCrossDissolve) {
    self.creditsLabel.textColor = .red
}
```

This is better than using NSTimers, CATextLayers and so on so forth for various reasons. CATextLayer does not have proper support for text kerning or NSAttributedText, and NSTimers are laggy (plus there's too much code). The transition animation above does the trick, and also can be used in a chain animation. I had the same issue and have already tried the solutions above but this simple code works wonders instead.

Comment: Great. Works in Swift just the same: `UIView.transitionWithView(creditsLabel, duration: 0.3, options: .TransitionCrossDissolve, animations: { self.creditsLabel.textColor = UIColor.redColor() }, completion: nil)`

Comment: just a note: This only works when label is static. If you do this and the label's position is being modified, the fade-out animation will show ugly artifact.

Comment: Doesn't work for me on Xcode 10.2.1 and Swift 5. 'shokaveli' method below does

Comment: I've been looking for a way to do this in SwiftUI, but it does not seem supported at the time.

Answer (score 62):

**Swift 4** solution:

```
UIView.transition(with: yourLabel, duration: 0.3, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
  self.yourLabel.textColor = .red
}, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Note, this only works if you have an instance of `UILabel` for the `with` property. If you do something like `transition(with: outerView.label…)` and try to set it inside, that will fail silently.

Comment: Doesn't work for me for some reason.  It is suddenly making the change instead of gradual during the animation. :(

Comment: @ScottyBlades maybe you are doing the animation on the background thread? Try wrapping the UIView.transition code inside the DispatchQueue.main.async { } brackets.

Comment: FYI - First time I tried didn't work and that was because i had `options: .easeInOut`, so I changed it to `.transitionCrossDissolve ` and worked.

Answer (score 13):

The reason that textColor is not animatable is that UILabel uses a regular CALayer instead of a CATextLayer.

To make textColor animatable (as well as text, font, etc.) we can subclass UILabel to make it use a CATextLayer.

This is quite a lot of work, but luckily I already did it :-)

You can find a complete explanation + a drop-in open source replacement for UILabel in this [article](http://corecocoa.wordpress.com/2011/10/04/animatable-text-color-of-uilabel/#more-30)

Answer (score 9):

You could try creating another instance of the UILabel or whatever it is that has the textColor, and then apply the animation between those two instances (the with the old textColor and the one with the new textColor).

Answer (score 9):

This was the ONLY thing that worked for me :

```
let changeColor = CATransition()
changeColor.duration = 1

CATransaction.begin()

CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
    selected.label.layer.add(changeColor, forKey: nil)
    selected.label.textColor = .black
}

selected.nameLabel.textColor = .red

CATransaction.commit()
```

Comment: Does anyone understand how/why this works...? Or specifically why does the CATransition only seem to work inside the completion block of CATransaction?

Answer (score 6):

Here's my code to animate label text color. The **important part is to set textColor to clearColor** before animation

```
label.textColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[UIView transitionWithView:label duration:duration/4 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{
    label.textColor = self.highlightedCellPrimaryTextColor;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) { }];
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it pretty easy placing an UIView below the label and animating its opacity. 
The label has to be added to that view. 
Maybe not a good solution from the resources consumption point of view, but pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

updated swift 3.0

I just changed from @budidino comments

```
UIView.transition(with: my.label, duration: 0.3, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: { my.label.textColor = .black }, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @**Strange**'s answer, working perfectly in Swift 5, Xcode 11 with a bit syntax change. I was animating text color for multiple UILabels, if this is also your case, try this

```swift
for label in [label1, label2, ...] as [UILabel] { // loop through a @IBOutlet UILabel array
        UIView.transition(with: label, duration: 0.3, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
            label.textColor = .label
        }, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using core animation

```
   func textColorBlinking(){
        let changeColor = CATransition()
        changeColor.duration = 1
        changeColor.type = .fade
        changeColor.repeatCount = Float.infinity
        CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
            self.lblHome.layer.add(changeColor, forKey: nil)
            self.lblHome.textColor = .white
        }
        self.lblHome.textColor = .red
        CATransaction.commit()
   }
```