# Animate UILabel to Change Colour?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, core-animation

I would like to make the text in my `UILabel` called `coloursLabel` change text colour by itself.  I have tried the following method as another SO answer suggested (albeit for the `backgroundColor`) but it still doesn't change.  Am I missing something silly?

```
UILabel *coloursLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    coloursLabel.text = @"This sentence is colourful!";
    [coloursLabel sizeToFit];
    coloursLabel.center = self.view.center;
    coloursLabel.frame = CGRectOffset(coloursLabel.frame, timeForPage(6), 0);

[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{
    coloursLabel.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    coloursLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    coloursLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    coloursLabel.textColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    coloursLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
} completion:NULL];
```

`coloursLabel` shows the correct text but the text is in black.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426614/how-to-animate-the-textcolor-property-of-an-uilabel

Answer (score 0):

UILabel's textColor is not animatable. You could write your own Label class, using a CATextLayer as mask and animate its layer's backgroundColor.