# Animate UILabel text color in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uilabel, calayer

How can I animate a color change of UILabel using swift? I have seen people mention using CALayer but I cannot figure out the Swift syntax.

This is an example of Objective-C

```
CALayer *layer = myView.layer;
CATextLayer *textLayer = [CATextLayer layer];
[textLayer setString:@"My string"];
[textLayer setForegroundColor:initialColor;
[textLayer setFrame:self.bounds];
[[self.view layer] addSublayer:textLayer];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
     textLayer.foregroundColor = finalColor;
   }];
```

Comment: I edited my original question to include an example of Objective-C

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to animate the textColor property of an UILabel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426614/how-to-animate-the-textcolor-property-of-an-uilabel)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

it is much easier than working with CALayer

```
let myLabel: UILabel!

UIView.animateWithDuration(2, animations: { () -> Void in
     myLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor();
})
```

Thats it...

**Edit**

Ok, sorry I didn't knew what color you want to change... I have converted your example to swift code...

first

```
import QuartzCore
```

than

```
if let layer: CALayer = self.view.layer as CALayer? {
    if let textLayer = CATextLayer() as CATextLayer? {
        textLayer.string = "My string"
        textLayer.foregroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        textLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(textLayer)

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { () -> Void in
            textLayer.foregroundColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: The text color changes but it does not animate. It changes instantly.

Comment: backgroundColor ≠ textColor, and as the question’s author points out, this doesn’t actually work

Comment: Thanks, sorry can't vote you up cause I don't have 15 reputation

Comment: At first, my first answer works... I checked it in Xcode, so first check it Noah, than write such stuff... At second, he edited his post, at my first answer I didn't know that the text color is meant... Now I have edited my post too, to fit his expectations

Comment: A down vote just because a lack of your knowledge... Nice work dude

Comment: user, you need to change the objects from self.view to your Label... But I guess you already saw this? :-)

Comment: First code snippet does't change the text color, which is actually what the author asked for and the second code doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, `textColor` isn't animatable via `UIView.animate`. However, `UIView.transition` works.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    
    UIView.transition(with: label, duration: 2, options: .transitionCrossDissolve) {
        self.label.textColor = .green
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Label's text color fades from black to green]