# Color of label does not change when used in animation

Tags: ios

```
 @IBAction func firstButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if textLabel.text == "Cat" {
            textLabel.backgroundColor = .green
            view.backgroundColor = .green
            secondButtonOutlet.isHidden = false
            firstButtonOutlet.isHidden = true
            picker.isHidden = true
            buttonBackOutlet.isHidden = false
        } else {
            secondButtonOutlet.isHidden = true
            countMistakes += 1
            view.backgroundColor = .systemRed
            textLabel.backgroundColor = .systemRed
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0, delay: 1, options: .allowAnimatedContent, animations: {
                () -> () in
                self.view.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.2392156869, green: 0.6745098233, blue: 0.9686274529, alpha: 1)
                self.textLabel.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.2392156869, green: 0.6745098233, blue: 0.9686274529, alpha: 1)
            }, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

I have this code. My goal is to make an animation of red screen blinking. Everything goes well until textLabel. It doesn't want to change its color at all. Can anyone help me how to fix it ? (Background color is changing, so the code should be correct in overall).

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67591642/14351818

Comment: @aheze I need a background color of the textLabel to be changed, not the text color

Comment: very unclear what you're question is asking ... you can set `textLabel.backgroundColor` to fully transparent (`UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0)`) and just animate `view.backgroundColor`

Comment: @CSmith actually that is a solution to my problem. It worked. Thanks!