# How to animate placeholder text color in UISearchBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar

I would like to animate placeholder text color in `UISearchBar`.

So I would like to have placeholder text going from gray to green and back to gray in 1 second and repeat for 8 times.

With help from comment I tried :

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.searchBar duration:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat animations:^{
        [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:8];
        [self.searchBar setValue:[UIColor greenColor] forKeyPath:@"_searchField._placeholderLabel.textColor"];
} completion:nil];
```

I added this code in `viewDidAppear` method.

But the problem is that the animation still does not work. It only changes the color of placeholder text without animation.

It only works with `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve` but I don't want that effect.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to animate the textColor property of an UILabel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426614/how-to-animate-the-textcolor-property-of-an-uilabel)

Comment: Thank you for help. Yes it works, but not the way I want it to work. Please se my updated version of the question.