# How can I make a UILabel text fade color?

Tags: ios, swift

I know how to fade the background. This is how I do it:

```
self.faderTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(self.fadeTime, target: self, selector: #selector(self.fadeBackground), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
func fadeBackground(){
    UIView.animateWithDuration(self.fadeTime, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction, animations: { [unowned self] () -> Void in
        self.fadeView.backgroundColor = UIColor.randomFlatColor()
    }) { (Bool) -> Void in

    }
}
```

How can I do the same thing with TextColor in UILabel?

Comment: can you cell `button.setTitleColor()` inside the animation block where you set the `backgroundColor`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426614/how-to-animate-the-textcolor-property-of-an-uilabel  someone posted a code to do this in swift.